# how to run windows application twice at the same time

Tags: windows, operating-system

As we know in windows OS,

many applications are designed as
 'can not run more than once at the same time'

is there any way we can make these applications running twice at the same time?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the application checks whether an instance is running while starting up and it checks that using the process name, then you can try creating a copy of the application binary and rename it and run. If the application is a network application , then it might check if a particular port it uses is in use or not. In such a case, you won't be able to run multiple instances of that app on the same port. Similar case for some other resource such as a file which if the application  locks, then another instance cannot read it and hence you cannot run more than one instances of it.

Answer (score 0):

example on a batch file

```
start /d "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\" "VirtualBox.exe"
start /d "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\" "VirtualBox.exe"
```

or try copy the `exe` file with different name like `VirtualBox1.exe` and try run both